# Can anyone help explain the 3rd solution to the AMC fall 12B question 17?

Tags: probability, generating-functions

So I have been looking at question 17 on the AMC 12B fall test and when looking at the 3rd solution, I couldn't really understand why the one can define c_n*x^n to be c_n ways for the destination to be n units away from the origin.

In general for generating functions there usually is a 1-to-1 correspondence, but I don't know what is that correspondence in this case, it would be helpful if anyone could explain (best with pictures) why this solution uses the generating function c_n*x^n works and where the 6x comes from.

Below is the link to the problem and its solution.
https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2021_Fall_AMC_12B_Problems/Problem_17

Comment: If you read Solution 3 as a version of Solution 1, it may be slightly easier: the coefficient of $x^1$ is the number of ways of being one away from the start, and the coefficient of $x^0$ is the number of ways of being at the start after the given number of steps.  $6x$ is saying there are six ways of going from the start to a position one away, so you can multiply the previous number of ways of being at the start by this

Comment: @Henry thanks for your response, it clears up my confusion.